# PHP Komodo getter/setter auto-generation

Tags: php, ide, komodo, komodoedit

Does Komodo support getter/setter auto generation a la NetBeans or Eclipse? If so how do I use it? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Wait, Eclipse does this? Or do you mean Zend Studio?

Comment: I should clarify- Eclipse does this for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Komodo [Edit/Open] supports it, not sure about Komodo IDE.

Answer (score 4):

This is a modified/improved version with a more readable code. Also will remove the default values from property declaration, like in `public $prop = array();`

```
from xpcom import components
import re

viewSvc = components.classes["@activestate.com/koViewService;1"]\
    .getService(components.interfaces.koIViewService)
view = viewSvc.currentView.queryInterface(components.interfaces.koIScintillaView)

sm = view.scimoz
sm.currentPos   # current position in the editor
sm.text         # editor text
                # sm.selText      # the selected text

output = u"\n"

setterTemplate = """
/**
 * Sets %s
 *
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return $this
 */
public function set%s($value) {
    $this->%s = $value;
    return $this;
}"""

getterTemplate = """
/**
 * Gets %s
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get%s() {
    return $this->%s;
}
"""

propertyTemplate = """%s
%s"""

prefixSizePv = len(u"private $")
prefixSizePu = len(u"public $")
prefixSizePr = len(u"protected $")

def formalName(rawName):
    return u"%s%s" % (rawName[0:1].upper(), rawName[1:])

#todo find a better way to split lines, what if its Mac or Windows format?
for line in sm.text.split("\n"):
    tmpLine = line.strip()
    hasPriv = tmpLine.startswith("private $")
    hasPublic = tmpLine.startswith("public $")
    hasProt = tmpLine.startswith('protected $')

    if hasPriv or hasPublic or hasProt:
        if hasPriv:
            realName = tmpLine[prefixSizePv:-1]
        elif hasPublic:
            realName = tmpLine[prefixSizePu:-1]
        else:
            realName = tmpLine[prefixSizePr:-1]

        realName = re.sub('\s?=.*', '', realName);

        formal = formalName(realName)
        output += propertyTemplate % ( setterTemplate %(realName, formal, realName), getterTemplate % (realName, formal, realName))

sm.insertText(sm.currentPos, output)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified version of David's code and works with the correct line endings:

```
from xpcom import components
import re

viewSvc = components.classes["@activestate.com/koViewService;1"]\
    .getService(components.interfaces.koIViewService)
view = viewSvc.currentView.queryInterface(components.interfaces.koIScintillaView)

sm = view.scimoz
sm.currentPos   # current position in the editor
sm.text         # editor text
sm.selText      # the selected text

output = u"\n"

setterTemplate = """
function set%s($value){
    $this->%s = $value;
}
"""

getterTemplate = """
/**
*@return string
*/
function get%s(){
    return $this->%s;
}
"""

propertyTemplate = """
%s

%s
"""

prefixSize = len(u"private $")

def formalName(rawName):
    return u"%s" % "".join([part.title() for part in rawName.split("_")])


eol = u"\n"           #UNIX \n (default) sm.eOLMode == 2
if sm.eOLMode == 0:   #DOS/Windows \r\n
    eol = u"\r\n"
elif sm.eOLMode == 1: #Mac Classic \r
    eol = u"\r"

for line in sm.text.split(eol):
    if line.strip().startswith("private $"):
        #trim of the private $ and trailing semi-colon
        realName = line.strip()[prefixSize:-1]        
        output += propertyTemplate % ( setterTemplate %(formalName(realName), realName), getterTemplate % (formalName(realName), realName))        



output = output.replace("\n", eol)
sm.insertText(sm.currentPos, output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither Komodo IDE nor Edit support it.

With PHP, what would you want to generate the code from?

- Eric

Comment: From the protected variables in the class

Answer (score 0):

This is in no way perfect or finished, but here's a Komodo 6 compatible python macro script I wrote to auto-generate setters/getters for an entire PHP class.

```
    from xpcom import components
    import re

    viewSvc = components.classes["@activestate.com/koViewService;1"]\
        .getService(components.interfaces.koIViewService)
    view = viewSvc.currentView.queryInterface(components.interfaces.koIScintillaView)

    sm = view.scimoz
    sm.currentPos   # current position in the editor
    sm.text         # editor text
    sm.selText      # the selected text
    #sm.text = "Hello World!"

    output = u"\n"

    setterTemplate = """
        function set%s($value){
            $this->%s = $value;
        }
    """

    getterTemplate = """
        /**
        *@return string
        */
        function get%s(){
            return $this->%s;
        }
    """

    propertyTemplate = """
    %s

    %s
    """

    prefixSize = len(u"private $")

    def formalName(rawName):
        return u"%s" % "".join([part.title() for part in rawName.split("_")])




    #todo find a better way to split lines, what if its Mac or Windows format?
    for line in sm.text.split("\n"):
        if line.strip().startswith("private $"):
            #trim of the private $ and trailing semi-colon
            realName = line.strip()[prefixSize:-1]        
            output += propertyTemplate % ( setterTemplate %(formalName(realName), realName), getterTemplate % (formalName(realName), realName))        



    sm.insertText(sm.currentPos, output)
```

give a file like foo.php with Class Bar as the only thing present

```
class Bar {
   private $id;
   private $name_first;
}
```

It would inject

```
    function setId($value){
        $this->id = $value;
    }



    /**
    *@return string
    */
    function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }



    function setNameFirst($value){
        $this->name_first = $value;
    }



    /**
    *@return string
    */
    function getNameFirst(){
        return $this->name_first;
    }
```

That's good enough for my uses ( I can retab everything pretty quickly ) but I'll update this answer if I improve significantly on the script.